# grouping array values like mysqli 'like' functionality

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

friends, i don't it's possible or not, anyway i want to group users who have same like preference names ( mysql 'like' functionality)

```
[0]=>
 array(5) {
  ["id"]=>"21"
  ["user_id"]=>"58"
  ["preference_id"]=>"4"
  ["sub_preference_id"]=>"7"
  ["preference_name"]=>"stephens collage"
}
[1]=>
 array(5) {
  ["id"]=>"22"
  ["user_id"]=>"52"
  ["preference_id"]=>"4"
  ["sub_preference_id"]=>"1"
  ["preference_name"]=>"st stephens"
}
[2]=>
 array(5) {
  ["id"]=>"25"
  ["user_id"]=>"61"
  ["preference_id"]=>"4"
  ["sub_preference_id"]=>"9"
  ["preference_name"]=>"joseph"
}
```

means i want output as like this :

1]stephens collage, st stephens

2] joseph

i tried this code :

```
$school_preference ="SELECT * FROM gic_user_preference where preference_id='4'";

$result_school_preference = mysqli_query($createCon->connect(), $school_preference);

$school = array();

 while ($show_school_preference = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_school_preference)) {

    $school_preference = $show_school_preference['sub_preference_id'];

    $get_all_school_preference =mysqli_query($createCon->connect(),"SELECT gic_user_preference.id,gic_user_preference.user_id,gic_user_preference.preference_id,gic_user_preference.sub_preference_id,gic_user_wise_school_preference.preference_name FROM gic_user_preference INNER JOIN gic_user_wise_school_preference ON gic_user_preference.sub_preference_id = gic_user_wise_school_preference.id where gic_user_preference.sub_preference_id='$school_preference'");

    while ($schools = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_all_school_preference)) {
        $school[$schools['preference_name']][] = $schools;
    }
 }
```

it's give the output

```
 array(4) {
 ["stephens collage"]=>
 array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "21"
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(2) "58"
  ["preference_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["sub_preference_id"]=>
  string(1) "7"
  ["preference_name"]=>
  string(16) "stephens collage"
   }
 }
  ["st stephens"]=>
  array(1) {
   [0]=>
   array(5) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "22"
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(2) "52"
  ["preference_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["sub_preference_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["preference_name"]=>
  string(11) "st stephens"
  }
 }
 ["joseph"]=>
 array(1) {
  [0]=>
   array(5) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "25"
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(2) "61"
  ["preference_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["sub_preference_id"]=>
  string(1) "9"
  ["preference_name"]=>
  string(6) "joseph"
  }
 }
}
```

any idea how to grouping this data as mysqli like function works ...

Comment: Can you please elaborate you want to group of the above array or merge this multiple array

Comment: How exactly are you defining which entries should be grouped together? What if you had a 4th entry were the `["preference_name"]` value was "st albans"

Comment: Soubhagya Kumar  , i want to grouping this users have same preference names ,

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use regular expression match for find same names!